# Last filled row Function behaves strangely based on column it's in

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, microsoft-excel-365

Function is acting very strange depending on column it's in. 
Data start at row `7` (headers in row `6`)
Column `A` has item name `B` Max Qty. `C` and `D` have simple functions and everything afterwards is the manually entered remaining Qty on certain dates.
Column `D` has

```
=((LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(7:7))),7:7))/B7)
```

Column C has

```
=100%-D7
```

Looks fine here:

[image: Looks fine here]

What this should do is we enter a value in `E` onward and it calculated % based on the LAST filled row of what's left and what's used. Works great EXCEPT when there is nothing after column `G`. It does not register/see/run when last value is in `E:G`.

[image: Not registering values]

Now when I delete Item column `A` and Max becomes the new `A` the problem, it works fine.

[image: No Item Column]

We did not realize this till we started a new 2019 sheet, we used it all 2018 but we had data from earlier dates that filled the problem columns.

Can someone please explain this and offer a solution?
We need the item column.

Comment: You have a circular reference since you're using `LOOKUP` against the entire row, including the cell the `LOOKUP` is in. This is causing you problems. Just changing the range of the `LOOKUP` does seem to solve the problem; replace formula in `D7` with: `=((LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(E7:ABC7))),E7:ABC7))/B7)`, for example, and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: I tried it with columns e7:7,obviously didn't work and quit after that. I didn't even realize I could do multicolumn abc:7. That worked thanks

Comment: `ABC7` is actually a single cell reference. `ABC` is the 731st column in an Excel worksheet. I just wanted an arbitrarily long range and my fingers went 'abc'. A more realistic range might be `E7:Z7`, all you need to do is ensure that it starts from `E7` and extends past any realistic limit to the number of columns you might use for data entry. `E7:7` is the same concept, unfortunately it's just not a syntax that Excel accepts.

Comment: The *cleanest* solution would be something along the lines of replacing the target range in that formula with an `INDIRECT` cell reference formula using another version of `LOOKUP` that returns the max non-blank column number in the row (which you can find at the same exceljet page that you got your `LOOKUP` formula from in the first place) to dynamically calculate the target range so you never have to worry about updating manually entered cell references (or writing them with arbitrarily long ranges in the first place). But, you know, who's got time for that